# Connecting MySQL database to Mac app

Tags: mysql, macos, cocoa, database-connection

The question is pretty simple, however it seems like there's a million variations on the answer, therefore although this question has definitely been asked before, I'd like to ask it again in the hope that an up-to-date answer can be sought.

Basically I'm creating a Mac app and part of it will be powered by data that I have in a remote MySQL database as part of my site. My question is this: what is the best way of connecting to that database so that the data can be used in my app?

I have read many answers that suggest using a web service to convert the database to JSON or equivalent and then converting that into objects that can be used via Core Data is the best way, however the data that I want is 'dumb', i.e. I won't be changing or manipulating it in anyway, therefore I think Core Data is potentially overkill for what I need.

Are there any other more straightforward ways of achieving this task?

Comment: A web service located on the site where the data lives is definitely the way to go...

Comment: @aserwin If that is the best way to go, is Core Data an integral part of that chain, or can it be bypassed? (Seems a little heavy-handed for what I need that's all.)

Comment: I wouldn't think it would be necessary. you just need to consume the service... you can do what with a web page. Admittedly, I don't know much about development for the Mac, and I don't know anything about Core Data (though I am aware of it hehe), but what you are proposing is pretty simple.

Comment: @aserwin Sorry, what do you mean by consume?

Comment: I would be careful about saying anything is "definitely" the way to go without learning more about your constraints. Depending on your needs, you should know about the MySQL C connector (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/connector-c.html) - you could use this API from your obj-c code very easily.

Comment: @SamHatchett I'll check it out, sounds like it might be able to help me a little.